# Is there a problem to solder only one side of a dual PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, soldering, pcb-assembly

If I do a double layer PCB (with the toner method) is there a problem if a solder the bottom side only? there are parts that are so hard to solder from the top layer, do I have to solder everything in the top and bottom layer? for example this is my PCB, and I want to solder a base in the pic slot so I can put and remove my PIC, but is hard to solder it in the top layer.
[image]

Comment: Through-hole parts should always be soldered from the opposite side of the PCB?

Comment: Ah, I understand: because you're doing it at home you don't have plated holes. In that case, it'll only work properly if all the tracks are on the side that you're soldering.

Comment: Indeed.  This is also not a board particularly well designed for the toner-transfer method.  You probably want to use thicker traces wherever possible, consider doing copper pours in some of the unused area to reduce the amount of etching needed, make the whole thing more compact, and seriously consider doing as much of it as possible with surface mount to save the time of drilling holes.

Comment: As it currently stands, you'd probably be better off building this on a piece of premade solderable breadboard PCB, rather than doing all that work and having to solder so many connections from the top side.  You don't seem to have any components with incompatible pin spacing, and through hole connectors can tend to break the foil on handmade PCBs without plated holes if not handled with extra care.

Comment: You could easily turn this into a single sided board if you make the top layer into jumper wires instead of copper traces. It would require a few modifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, is plated hole, the hole that connect to both layers?

Comment: @Pulse9: Yes. Also abbreviated PTH and called vias in the case of SMT boards...

Comment: Thanks, so the vias, or green holes, are automatically considered PTH if I send the design to a PCB manufacturer?

Comment: @Pulse9 that's something that you should ask the PCB fab you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem. You won't have reliable connections from the top tracks to the components unless the holes are plated through - which seems unlikely as you are making the boards yourself.

If you haven't made the board yet you could:

1. Make a single sided board and use wire jumpers to bridge across tracks where needed. Much simpler to make and all soldering is on one side.
2. If you really want to try a double-sided board then use pins (Vero used to make these in my youth) or wire links to connect through the board. The pins would have to be soldered both sides of the board but all the components only on the bottom. So, if blue tracks are on the top side, the PIC pin 1 would need a short track on the bottom side to a through hole to the top side to connect to the blue track somewhere other than at pin 1 itself.